# Silex SessionServiceProvider gives me a download in Windows 8

Tags: php, windows, silex

I'm trying to get SessionServiceProvider to work in my project but if I register it, the page is given to me as a download which contains a misconfigured server error.

My error logs don't show anything and the same code works in my virtual linux environment.

I use Windows 8 and zend server.

This is the line of code causing all the trouble:

```
$app->register(new SessionServiceProvider());
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

It seems looking at:
http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/session.html

They implement all the logic on saving the session themselves when the default provider is used. So maybe on Windows you dont have access to the C:\Windows\Temp folder that is the default one specified there to save the session, try overriding that manually to something you know your server has access to? Can you provide more details about the exact error you get (any error codes, the source of the page you download, anything at all in the apache or php logs).

Also since you mentioned you use Zend server, I am not familiar with it, but I remember it offers a lot of the services with its own implementation so there might be a built-in session handler that comes bundled with Zend server already, in which case you might want to refer to the last paragraph of that link I posted and try to set the handler to null.